# mininet cannot find required executable ifconfig?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I was trying to install mininet on my virtual box and came across this error.

*** Creating network

*** Adding controller

Cannot find required executable ifconfig.

Please make sure that Mininet is installed and available in your $PATH:

(/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

Answer (score 5):

Try using the following in the terminal,

```
apt install net-tools
```

Comment: Thanks, `sudo apt install net-tools` worked for me in Ubuntu18.04